# Compare the first element of each row in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check all matching elements in the first element (left side) of each row, and if there's a match, get the elements next to it.

Here's what I have got as an example:

```
ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> attribute = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[][] sample = {   {"hates", "hates"},
                                {"p1","boy"},
                                {"p2","girl"}, 
                                {"hatesCopy", "hatesCopy"}, 
                                {"p2","boy"}, 
                                {"p1","girl"}};

        for(int a = 0; a < sample.length; a++){
            for(int b = 0; b < sample.length; b++){
                if(sample[b].equals(sample[a])){
                    variables.add(sample[b][0]);
                    attribute.add(sample[b][1]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("variables stored: "+ variables);
        System.out.println("attributes stored: "+ attribute);
```

I have tried to compare the first element of each row in the 2d array to check if there exists a matching element, but it isn't working the way I want it to.

The variables and attributes array should output:

```
variables stored: [p1, p1, p2, p2]
attribute stored: [boy, girl, girl, boy]
```

Where the first element "p1" is value next to it "boy" from the sample 2d array.

But instead, my code decides to output the entire thing of the 2D array which is wrong:

```
variables stored: [hates, p1, p2, hatesCopy, p2, p1]
attribute stored: [hates, boy, girl, hatesCopy, boy, girl]
```

Also, the length of the row varies, but the column will always be the size of 2.
Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: `sample` is a 2D array, yet you are checking `sample[b].equals(sample[a])`. That compares 1D arrays, not String elements. You need two indexes to get an element (ex: `sample[b][c]`).

Comment: Yeah I tried that using sample[b][0].equals(sample[a][0] and only outputs:  variables stored: [hates, p1, p1, p2, p2, hatesCopy, p2, p2, p1, p1]
attribute stored: [hates, boy, girl, girl, boy, hatesCopy, girl, boy, boy, girl]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking elements against themselves.  There is only one copy of `"hates"` and `"hatesCopy"`, but they match against themselves.

To prevent self matches, add a condition to make sure `a` doesn't equal `b`.

```
if(a != b && sample[b][0].equals(sample[a][0])){
```

Comment: Ohh crap, how the hell did I not think of that :(.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Shall remember a!=b next time.